# file chooser to choose folder (android)

Tags: android

i am using [afilechooser](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser) for this purpose . and this is by default programmed to choose the items inside the folder and get you the path that is selected by the user.

but i want to use this as folder chooser where the user choose a location from internal memory of android device and then the app will save the file at that location.

so how do i do it.

the code i am using for this purpose is-

```
private void showChooser() {
    // Use the GET_CONTENT intent from the utility class
    Intent target = FileUtils.createGetContentIntent();
    // Create the chooser Intent
    Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(
            target, getString(R.string.chooser_title));
    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // The reason for the existence of aFileChooser
    }
}
```

and i suspect the code can be changed to choose the folder instead of files. any suggestion can be helpful . please suggest if any other way to achieve what is want .

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the github project in the url you posted, it doesn't look like this can be achieved. My claim is based on the following piece of code inside `com.ipaulpro.afilechooser.FileChooserActivity` class:

```
@Override
public void onFileSelected(File file) {
    if (file != null) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            replaceFragment(file);
        } else {
            finishWithResult(file);
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(FileChooserActivity.this, R.string.error_selecting_file,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

just look at the `if(file.isDirectory())` statement.

Comment: can you please suggest any other alternatives for this ?

Comment: No I do not know any alternatives, however since you already have the code in your workspace you could try to adapt it to work as you wish.

Comment: i want to select folder to choose path for saving files. but this is choosing the items in the folder . anyway i will continue to work on it.

Comment: Yes it does so because looking at the code I posted above if the selected `File` is directory then it runs the `replaceFragment()` method and only if it is not directory it calls `finishWithResult()` which leads to getting the file uri. You can try to tweak the code in the `onFileSelected` method.

Comment: i will give it a try and let you know .